# cant get required fields from containable model cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have a hasmany relationship between Guardian ans Student. A Guardian hasmany Students. I cant get the required fields from containable object students, instead I get everything from Students but I do get the required fields from Guardian.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

```
   $this->Guardian->Behaviors->load('Containable'); 
    $guardians =$this->Guardian->find('all',array( 
                'contain'=>array('Student',
                    array( 'fields'=> array('Student.guardian_id,Student.id,Student.first_name' ))),

               'order' => array('guardian_first_name ASC'),
             'fields'=> array('Guardian.guardian_first_name,Guardian.guardian_last_name,Guardian.id' ),
               'recursive'=> -1      
              ));

array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Guardian' => array(
            'guardian_first_name' => '',
            'guardian_last_name' => '',
            'id' => '166'
        ),
        'Student' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '166',
                'student_inactive' => true,
                'student_enq' => false,
                'student_unallocated' => false,
                'first_name' => 'Kala',
                'last_name' => 'narayanan',
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fields` option is not nested correctly, which you maybe would have noticed if you'd format your code properly, something along the lines of this:

```
$this->Guardian->Behaviors->load('Containable'); 
$guardians = $this->Guardian->find('all', array( 
    'contain' => array(
        'Student',
        array(
            'fields'=> array(
                'Student.guardian_id,Student.id,Student.first_name'
            )
        )
    ),
    'order' => array(
        'guardian_first_name ASC'
    ),
    'fields' => array(
        'Guardian.guardian_first_name,Guardian.guardian_last_name,Guardian.id'
    ),
    'recursive'=> -1
));
```

The array holding the `fields` option must be passed as the value for `Student` key.

```
// ...
'contain' => array(
    'Student' => array(
        'fields'=> /* ...*/
    )
),
// ...
```

On a side note, when passing the fields as a comma separated string (which might not be the best idea), it's not necessary to pass them in an array.

Comment: This doesnt work sorry as I get the same output of student fields as before. Your code is no different to mine BTW

Comment: @ajt Why would you expect that anything changes when the code is the same? Anyways, please read my answer more carefully, the first block of code is just yours in a properly formatted fashion, so that you can see your mistake, and maybe realize that formatting is important. The second block of code has the "fix", which is also explained in text form.

Answer (score 0):

array(
            'fields'=> array(
                guardian_id, id, first_name'
            )
        )

use fields without model name.